# How to show the input field value in another input field using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs. I'm bit confused how to do it, i want to write something in first input field and at the same time it should reflect on the second input field. If i delete the value in the first input field then it should delete the second input field also. Can anybody help me in this?

Here is the Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: ""
    };
  }

  handleName = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form>
          <Input
            placeholder="Name"
            onChange={this.handleName}
            name="name"
            value={this.state.name}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={this.handleName}
            name="email"
            value="@yahoo.com"
          />
        </Form>
        <Button>Submit</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

code: "https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-fast-3w8sz"

Comment: change second Input value property into `value={this.state.name}` . Also, I recommend to [read more about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use same `{this.state.name}` as a value for both field. for example:

```
<Input
            placeholder="Name"
            onChange={this.handleName}
            name="name"
            value={this.state.name}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={this.handleName}
            name="email"
            value={this.state.name}
          />
```

Comment: You can also add some custom text for example `value={\`${this.state.name}@yahoo.com\`}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `yahoo.com` as suffix with the in the second input replace the `value` prop of the input field with `` value={`${this.state.name}yahoo.com`} ``. Hope this is what you are looking for